# I made a Form in Bootstrap 4. i want to receive all values by email when user fill and submit the form

Tags: php, email, bootstrap-4

I made a Form in Bootstrap 4. i want to receive all values by email  when user fill and submit the form.

Comment: Even though you received a couple of answers below let me tell you that we are not here to do the whole job for you. We are here to help you fix your code errors. Show us what you have tried so that we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $to = 'enter@emailId';
    $subject = "Enter your subject here";
    $from = $email;//fetch from post

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Create email headers
    $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
          'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
          'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $message = "Write your message here";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

check if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a another PHP page that takes the values on the $_POST, and once you have got all the values you can use PHPMailer to send all the values on email.

Check out this Github link, it will help
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer